# Make a second "table of contents" incorporating a short summary for each section

Tags: table-of-contents, abstract

Suppose I have a document looking like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A}
\subsection{A.A}    \subsection{A.B}
\section{B}
\subsection{B.A}    \subsection{B.B}

\end{document}
```

I would like to add a short summary for each section, and produce a second table of contents after the first one, that would include this summary. The end result could look like this:

> **Contents**
> *[normal table of contents]*
>
> **Summary**
> **1 A**
> This section is about stuff.
>
> **2 B**
> This section is about whatever.
>
> *[rest of the document]*

Obviously I can achieve the result by hand, but I'd rather not. For example it would be great if I could put the summary at the beginning of the section (in the code) and have it automatically be put in the "summary toc" at the right place.

Bonus question: I'd like to do all of that with a KOMA-script class. So if possible, no memoir-specific magic should be used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do these things with [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc):

---

**Note:** *for an elaboration (incorporating the remark below) of the technique see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165838/4686) to [Expanded toc-like environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165773/expanded-toc-like-environment)*

---

**Remark:** The code below defines a command `\sectionsummary` which ultimately writes things to the  `.toc` file. It thus has the same difficulties with fragile commands that the `\section` command has. To get the material given as argument to `\sectionsummary` find its way unexpanded to the `.toc` file, one can use the following which uses the `e-TeX` primitive `\unexpanded`.

```
\newcommand*{\sectionsummary}[1]%
        {\etoctoccontentsline{sectionsummary}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}}
```

With this variant, material given as argument to `\sectionsummary` will only get expanded when the `Summary` gets typeset.

> [image: summarytoc]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetlevel {sectionsummary}{6}

\newcommand*{\sectionsummary}[1]{\etoctoccontentsline{sectionsummary}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\etocsettocstyle {\bigskip\noindent\bfseries\sffamily\Large 
                  Summary\par\normalfont\normalsize}{}

% section headings exactly as in the standard TOC
\makeatletter
    \let\original@l@section\l@section
    \etocsetstyle {section}{}{}% cf etoc manual, "Another compatibility mode"
       {\original@l@section{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}
\makeatother

% now setting a style to print the summaries:
\etocsetlevel {sectionsummary}{2}
\etocsetstyle {sectionsummary}{\parindent1.5em\normalfont}
                              {\etocname}{\par}{\medskip}

% subsections a priori at level 2, need to be moved out of the way
\etocsetlevel {subsection}{6}

\etocsettocdepth {sectionsummary}
\tableofcontents
% can be located anywhere in the document. 
% (but if before the main TOC, or before some other TOC, put everything in a
% group, to limit the scope of our style changes)

\section{A}
\sectionsummary{This section is about stuff.}% one paragraph only please.
\sectionsummary{Oh, and I forgot to say that also.}% another paragraph.

Hello
\subsection{A.A}    
Hello

\subsection{A.B}
Hello

\section{B}
\sectionsummary{This section is about whatever.}

\subsection{B.A}    \subsection{B.B}

\end{document}
```