# Expanded toc-like environment

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm typesetting a book. It has a special toc-like text at the beginning of each
chapter.

What I want to do is: use after each section an environment (say abstract) and get
the result at the beginning of each chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
    \begin{abstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item First this abstract talks about....
            \item Second we have ...
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{abstract}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\section{First Section}
    \begin{abstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item this section talks about ....
            \item it also tals about
        \end{\itemize*}
    \end{abstract}

bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

result:

```
First Chapter
-- First this abstract talks about.... -- Second we have ...
1. First Section: -- this section talks about .... -- it also talks about

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

*First Section*
bla bla bla
```

Is this possible?

Note that this isn't just minitoc, because each section will have a summary in the toc.

Edit: the description is actually an `itemize*` environment provided by the `enumitem` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Have you seen [Table of Contents with additional description of entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/)?

Comment: @cgnieder: no, I did't see it. I'll look into it and try to combine the solution with minitoc, thanks.

Comment: also perhaps related [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146059/make-a-second-table-of-contents-incorporating-a-short-summary-for-each-section](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146059/make-a-second-table-of-contents-incorporating-a-short-summary-for-each-section)

Comment: Should the descriptive text appear in the patial ToC only, or should it also appear in the main ToC and in the document body? Are you bound to use `minitoc` or would you be willing to use another package to produce the partial ToCs?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: the descriptive text appears only in the partial toc. I don't care about minitoc.

Comment: @jfbu: I tried the solution provided by your link. It looked very promising until I hit the line `\sectionsummary ... % one paragraph ...`. My description is in fact an itemize* environment provided by the enumitem package.

Comment: @shilluc you should have mentioned that in the first place. Please add that new information as an edit to your question.

Comment: @shilluc Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I have adapted to your set-up the solution I linked to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to do it with [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc). I have added a "minitoc" of chapter abstracts, additionally to the tocs of section abstracts, one per chapter.

The update adds a second code sample in response to comments: how to use the method with unnumbered chapters (`\chapter*`) and how to use `enumerate*` rather than `enumerate` for the gathering of section chapters done at the start of each (now unnumbered) chapter.

page 1

> [image: abstracts 1]

page 3

> [image: abstracts 2]

page 5

> [image: abstracts 3]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}% checking compatibility (also for pdf bookmarks)

\etocsetlevel{chapterabstract}{6}% invisible in TOCs unless level changed
\etocsetlevel{sectionabstract}{6}% invisible in TOCs unless level changed

\usepackage{environ}

%%%%

\NewEnviron {sectionabstract}{%
   \expandafter\SaveSectionAbstract\expandafter {\BODY}%
}%

\newcommand\SaveSectionAbstract [1]{%
   \etoctoccontentsline{sectionabstract}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}}

\NewEnviron {chapterabstract}{%
   \expandafter\SaveChapterAbstract\expandafter {\BODY}%
}%

\newcommand\SaveChapterAbstract [1]{%
   \etoctoccontentsline{chapterabstract}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}}

%%%%

\newcommand\PrintSectionAbstracts {%
    \begingroup
% level must be set *before* use of \etocsetstyle
       \etocsetlevel {sectionabstract}{2}
       \etocsetnexttocdepth {sectionabstract}
       \etocsetlevel {subsection}{3}   
       \etocsetstyle {section}
          {\begin{enumerate}}
          {}
          {\item \etocname:~}
          {\end{enumerate}}
       \etocsetstyle {sectionabstract}
          {}
          {}
          {\etocthename\par}
          {}
       \etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{Section abstracts}}{}
       \localtableofcontents
    \endgroup
}   

\newcommand\PrintChapterAbstracts {%
    \begingroup
       \etocsetlevel {chapterabstract}{1}
       \etocsetnexttocdepth {chapterabstract}
       \etocsetlevel {section}{2}   
       \etocsetstyle {chapter}
          {\begin{enumerate}}
          {}
          {\item \etocname:~}
          {\end{enumerate}}
       \etocsetstyle {chapterabstract}
          {}
          {}
          {\etocthename\par}
          {}
       \etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{Chapter abstracts}}{}
       %\localtableofcontents 
       % better not local, as the main TOC itself, a priori printed before,
       % could have been configured to create a chapter entry in the toc file
       \tableofcontents
    \endgroup
}   

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % standard table of contents

\PrintChapterAbstracts % chapter abstracts

\chapter{First Chapter}
   \begin{chapterabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item First this chapter talks about....
            \item Second we have ...
        \end{itemize*}
   \end{chapterabstract}

\PrintSectionAbstracts % section abstracts

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\section{First Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item this first section talks about Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
              consetetur sadipscing elitr \dots
            \item it also talks about \dots
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\section{Second Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
        \item this second section talks about ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
          sadipscing elitr,
        \item it also talks about sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
          justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\section{Third  Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
        \item this third section talks about ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
          sadipscing elitr,
        \item it also talks about sed diam voluptua.
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\chapter{Second Chapter}
   \begin{chapterabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
        \item First this second chapter talks about ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
          labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
          et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        \item Second we have clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        \end{itemize*}
   \end{chapterabstract}

\PrintSectionAbstracts % section abstracts

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\section{First Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item this first section of the second chapter talks about \dots
            \item it also talks about \dots
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\section{Second Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item this section talks about \dots
            \item it also talks about \dots
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\section{Third  Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item this third section talks about ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
            \item it also talks about sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

**Remark**: this is a further elaboration of my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146081/4686) to [Make a second "table of contents" incorporating a short summary for each section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146059/make-a-second-table-of-contents-incorporating-a-short-summary-for-each-section). The new thing is the use of package [environ](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) to allow an environment rather than a command syntax. Apart from that this is essentially the same technique.

---

*Update*:

page of the main table of contents (notice that it is using the class default reserved spaces for the section numbers, which here is too big as chapters are left unnumbered; you can either use `etoc` more fully, see the manual for examples, or use for example `tocloft` to customize this main TOC printed in *compatibility mode*).

The chapter abstracts are printed using a `description` environment.

> [image: section abstracts II 1]

page of first chapter

> [image: section abstracts II 2]

page of second chapter

> [image: section abstracts II 3]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}% checking compatibility (also for pdf bookmarks)

\etocsetlevel{chapterabstract}{6}% invisible in TOCs unless level changed
\etocsetlevel{sectionabstract}{6}% invisible in TOCs unless level changed

\usepackage{environ}

%%%%

\NewEnviron {sectionabstract}{%
   \expandafter\SaveSectionAbstract\expandafter {\BODY}%
}%

\newcommand\SaveSectionAbstract [1]{%
   \etoctoccontentsline{sectionabstract}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}}

\NewEnviron {chapterabstract}{%
   \expandafter\SaveChapterAbstract\expandafter {\BODY}%
}%

\newcommand\SaveChapterAbstract [1]{%
   \etoctoccontentsline{chapterabstract}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}}

%%%%

\newcommand\PrintSectionAbstracts {%
    \begingroup
% level must be set *before* use of \etocsetstyle
       \etocsetlevel {sectionabstract}{2}
       \etocsetnexttocdepth {sectionabstract}
       \etocsetlevel {subsection}{3}  
% enumitem redefinition of \item causes the closing of groups
% hence either some \expandafter, or like here \global saving
% of number and name 
       \etocsetstyle {section}
          {\begin{enumerate*}}
          {\global\let\EtocNumber\etocthenumber
           \global\let\EtocName\etocthelinkedname}
          {\item [{\bfseries\EtocNumber.}~]\EtocName: }
          {\end{enumerate*}}
       \etocsetstyle {sectionabstract}
          {}
          {}
          {\etocthename\par}
          {}
       \etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{Section abstracts}}{\medskip}
       \localtableofcontents
    \endgroup
}   

\newcommand\PrintChapterAbstracts {%
    \begingroup
       \etocsetlevel {chapterabstract}{1}
       \etocsetnexttocdepth {chapterabstract}
       \etocsetlevel {section}{2}   
       \etocsetstyle {chapter}
          {\begin{description}}
          {}
          {\item[\etocname] }
          {\end{description}}
       \etocsetstyle {chapterabstract}
          {}
          {}
          {\etocthename\par}
          {}
       \etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{Chapter abstracts}}{}
       \tableofcontents
    \endgroup
}   

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\tableofcontents % standard table of contents

\PrintChapterAbstracts % chapter abstracts

\chapter*{First Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{First Chapter}

   \begin{chapterabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item First this chapter talks about....
            \item Second we have ...
        \end{itemize*}
   \end{chapterabstract}

\PrintSectionAbstracts % section abstracts

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\section{First Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item this first section talks about Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
              consetetur sadipscing elitr \dots
            \item it also talks about \dots
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\subsection{this subsection should not create problems}

\section{Second Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
        \item this second section talks about ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
          sadipscing elitr,
        \item it also talks about sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
          justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\section{Third  Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
        \item this third section talks about ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
          sadipscing elitr,
        \item it also talks about sed diam voluptua.
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\chapter*{Second Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Second Chapter}

   \begin{chapterabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
        \item First this second chapter talks about ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
          labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
          et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
        \item Second we have clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        \end{itemize*}
   \end{chapterabstract}

\PrintSectionAbstracts % section abstracts

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\section{First Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item this first section of the second chapter talks about \dots
            \item it also talks about \dots
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\section{Second Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
        \begin{itemize*}
            \item this section talks about \dots
            \item it also talks about \dots
        \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\section{Third  Section}

    \begin{sectionabstract}
    \begin{itemize*}
    \item this third section talks about ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
      sadipscing elitr,
    \item it also talks about sed diam voluptua.
    \end{itemize*}
    \end{sectionabstract}

bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: if one needs some kind of section summary with multi-paragraph contents, then `\endgraf` should be used to delimit the paragraphs rather than `\par` or empty lines. Indeed, the `etoc` macro fetching the "name" from the `.toc` file does not allow `\par`'s or empty lines (the kernel `\addcontentsline` does not either.)

Comment: It's almost there. But the solution don't behave very well when used with \chapter*. So I can't automate it by redefinig \chapter.

Comment: do you know why if I replace the `enumerate` environment by `enumerate*`, the titles of sections `\etocname` simply disapear.

Comment: @shilluc: my update to the answer incorporate my two previous comments which ultimately will get deleted. I just for the record re-say that `{\expandafter\item \etocthelinkedname:~}` was a way to address the problem with `enumitem` `\item` closing groups in environment `enumerate*`. The answer does it a bit otherwise because it needs both the number and the name.

Comment: the new modification changes the number format to 1.1. 1.2. ..., apart from that it's perfect

Comment: @shilluc no, not the second code sample I posted. If you copy paste it in its entirety, sections are numbered `1`, `2`, etc..

Answer (score 7):

Here's a possibility using the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package to generate the partial ToCs and a variation of [Martin Sharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10189/3954) to [Table of Contents with additional description of entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/) to include the additional section description in the partial ToC:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@nodottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{\,}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor }%
     \par}%
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@sectioninfo{\@nodottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\NewEnviron{sectioninfo}{%
    \addcontentsline{ptc}{sectioninfo}{%
    \noexpand\numberline{}\BODY}%
}
\makeatother

\def\PrintContents{%
\startcontents%
\printcontents{}{1}{{\bfseries\Large\contentsname}%
  \par\nobreak\vskip-6pt\noindent\hrulefill}%
  \vskip-6pt\noindent\hrulefill\vskip3\baselineskip%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\PrintContents

\lipsum[4]

\section{First section of chapter one}
\begin{sectioninfo}
\protect\begin{itemize*}
\protect\item The first important thing about this section.
\protect\item The second important thing about this section.
\protect\item The third important thing about this section.
\protect\end{itemize*}%
\end{sectioninfo}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Second section of chapter one}
\begin{sectioninfo}
\protect\begin{itemize*}
\protect\item The first important thing about this section.
\protect\item The second important thing about this section.
\protect\item The third important thing about this section.
\protect\item The fourth important thing about this section.
\protect\end{itemize*}%
\end{sectioninfo}
\lipsum[4]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\PrintContents

\lipsum[4]

\section{First section of chapter two}
\begin{sectioninfo}
\protect\begin{itemize*}
\protect\item The first important thing about this section.
\protect\item The second important thing about this section.
\protect\end{itemize*}%
\end{sectioninfo}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Second section of chapter two}
\begin{sectioninfo}
\protect\begin{itemize*}
\protect\item The first important thing about this section.
\protect\item The second important thing about this section.
\protect\item The third important thing about this section.
\protect\end{itemize*}%
\end{sectioninfo}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

An image of the general ToC:

[image]

And some images of the partial ToCs:

[image]

and

[image]

### Remark

The descriptions are provided with a `sectioninfo` environment; inside this environment fragile comments need to be protected; since `itemize*` (from `enumitem`) is used in the descriptions, `\begin{itemize*}`, `\end{itemize*}` and `\item` need a prepended `\protect`.

Comment: Is it possible to delete the dots, the page number, have just the section number (without the chapter) and have the description in the same line as the section title?