# paragraph writing

Tags: paragraphs, typography

How can I achieve typesetting as can be seen in the following picture? I especially would like to know how the paragraphs can be written in Latex. *Chapter 2* (etc.) seems to be written with bigger font size. How can the indentation be achieved for each paragraph?

I would highly appreciate a minimal working example resembling a text structure as seen in the image below.

[image]

Comment: `\begin{description}
\item[label] description
\end{description}`

Comment: For an automated solution, maybe have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165838/36296

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using `description` list.

```
\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\section{title}
\section{Structure}
\begin{description}
\item[Chapter 2] lipsum*[2]

\item[Chapter 3] lipsum*[3]
\end{description}
```

[image]

Comment: The labels are written in a sans serif font in @beta's image. So `\item[\sffamily Chapter 2]` is closer.

Comment: I'd use `\item[\textsf{Chapter 2}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Sigur's answer is just the right solution. It does the job, cleanly and easily, but what fun is to take always the easy way?

Here you are two (some more convoluted) ways to obtain the same, but  without any environment, where is easy include auto-numbered labels and even add these to the TOC. May be these are more consistent reasons than "for fun" ...  others could be that you need several description-like numbered paragraphs and/or with different styles that can be mixed anywhere. Have fun.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% page layout (optional)
\pagestyle{plain}\parskip.3em
% dummy example text 
\def\dummytext{This is a long dummy sentence that mean 
nothing and take only some more that one line. }
\begin{document}

\section{Kinky use of \texttt{\textbackslash paragraph}}

% ===== settings =====
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{2em}{5em}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex\hangindent3em}{-1em}%
{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\theparagraph{Chapter \arabic{paragraph}}

% ===== Check of TOC results ======
{\footnotesize
\renewcommand\contentsname{\hrulefill}
\tableofcontents\hrulefill
}


% ===== Use examples ======= 
\setcounter{paragraph}{1} % Omit Chapter 1
\paragraph{} \dummytext\par          % Numbered label 
\dummytext                           % Normal paragraph whitin the pseudo-list 

\paragraph[\mbox{}]{}  \dummytext            % Numbered label in TOC 
\paragraph*{Annex A}  \dummytext\dummytext   % Custom label
\paragraph[description]{The Last Chapter}    % Custom numbered label in TOC  
\dummytext\dummytext


\section{Autonumbered macro \texttt{\textbackslash chapdescr}}

% ===== definition =====
\newcounter{chapterdescr}\setcounter{chapterdescr}{1}
\def\chapdescr{%
\addtocounter{chapterdescr}{1}\par\noindent%
\hangindent3em\textbf{\sffamily Chapter \arabic{chapterdescr}}\hskip1em}

% ===== Use examples ======= 
\chapdescr    \dummytext\par
There are no option here, nor special paragraph skips nor 
entries in TOC.  You can use also normal paragraphs 
whitin the pseudo-description lists. 
\chapdescr    \dummytext\dummytext

\end{document}
```