# Annotated table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

To help structuring a large document, I'd like to summarise the key points at the start of a section (or sub(sub)section or chapter) using bullet points and include them in the table of content page. If possible, I would also like to enable/disable the summary (in the section and in the toc). Is there already a package that allows for that or can someone give some ideas for some commands to use?

The final result should look like:

```
Table of Content
   Introduction..........1
      * some text introducing the topic
      * more text
   Background............5
      * Background section blah, blah
   Chapter 1............10
      * ...
   ...


   Introduction
      * some text introducing the topic
      * more text
      This is the text for the actual introduction. Summary bullet
      points are show because "draft" flag is set.
      More intro text here...

   Background
      ...

   Chapter 1
      ...
```

I found a similar question being asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/table-of-contents-with-additional-description-of-entries), but when I try to include a itemize environment (e.g. in chapterinfo), I get an error message:

> Chapter 1.
>   )
>   ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line
>   56.  
>                   \fi

It would be nice if someone could provide hints for how to make this section-type agnostic (i.e. not using `chapterinfo`, `sectioninfo`) and more importantly how to make this an environment, i.e. by using something like:

```
\section{Introduction}
\begin{summary}
  \item some text introducing the topic
  \item more text
\end{summary}
```

The fact that the summary doesn't isn't actually also appearing in the text isn't much of a problem for me.

Comment: A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) would be nice.

Comment: I had no idea where to start which is why I couldn't provide an example. However, after some more searching, I found an example that gets close to what I need. Please have a look at the updated description.

Comment: But what class are you using?

Comment: @Johannes_B: class "report".

Comment: Just add a COMPLETE MWE. It starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}` including all necessary packages to recreate your issues/results. And [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165838/4686 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146081/4686 will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might be a starting point. You might tweak the `itemize` environment to use smaller spaces and stuff.

```
\documentclass[draft]{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newif\ifSummaryInToC
\newif\ifSummaryInText
\SummaryInToCtrue
\SummaryInTexttrue

\makeatletter
\long\def\grabsummary#1#2\end{%
  \ifSummaryInToC\applysummary{#1}{#2}\fi%
  \ifSummaryInText\applydraftsummary{#2}\fi%
  \end}
\long\def\applysummary#1#2{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{%
    \bgroup%
    \let\BEGIN\begin%
    \let\END\end%
    \expandafter\ifcase\numexpr#1+1\relax%
      \vspace*{1ex}% part needs more distance in ToC than the others
    \else%
      \vspace*{-1ex}%
    \fi%
    \expandafter\ifcase\numexpr#1+1\relax%
      \@tempdima=1em\relax% indentation for part-level
    \or%
      \@tempdima=2.3em\relax% indentation for chapter-level
    \or%
      \@tempdima=3.8em\relax% indentation for section-level
    \or%
      \@tempdima=7em\relax% indentation for subsection-level
    \or%
      \@tempdima=11.1em\relax% indentation for subsubsection-level
    \else%
      \@tempdima=1.7em\relax% fallback indentation
    \fi%
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\@tempdima]%
      \baselineskip=0.5\baselineskip% crude way of changing the space
      \parskip=0pt% crude way of changing the space between items
      \parsep=0pt% crude way of changing the space between items
      \itemsep=2pt% crude way of changing the space between items
        #2%
    \end{itemize}%
    \egroup%
  }}}}
\long\def\applydraftsummary#1{%
  \hrule width \textwidth\kern4pt%
  \textbf{Summary}%
  \begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}%
  \hrule width \textwidth\medskip}%
\newenvironment{summary}[1][0]{\let\BEGIN\begin\let\END\end\grabsummary{#1}}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{FOO} % summary is not on the same page as heading
\begin{summary}[-1]
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{summary}
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{summary}
    \item foo
    \item bar
    \item baz
    \item very long bullet point that describes very much and eventually needs a
      line break
    \BEGIN{itemize}
      \item test
    \END{itemize}
    \item foo
\end{summary}
This is the text for the actual Foo.
Summary bullet points are shown because \verb|\SummaryInTexttrue| is set.
If \verb|\SummaryInToCtrue| is also set, these bullet points show up in the ToC,
too!
\section{Foobar}
\begin{summary}[1]
  \item Foo
    \BEGIN{itemize}
      \item foo
      \item bar
    \END{itemize}
  \item Bar
\end{summary}
\subsection{foobar}
\begin{summary}[2]
  \item Foo
    \BEGIN{itemize}
      \item foo
      \item bar
    \END{itemize}
  \item Bar
\end{summary}
\chapter{Bar}
\begin{summary}
    \item foo
    \item bar
    \item baz
\end{summary}
\section{Foobaz}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I changed the answer to cope everything you asked for (I think). If something is missing, feel free to ask.

You should not nest an environment in the `summary` environment, because `\grabsummary` scans for `\end` and if it encounters a `\end` stops. I've made another edit, which allows the use of nested environments with `\BEGIN` and `\END` (technically the `\BEGIN` part isn't necessary, but I think it looks better if they match). Note that the definitions of `\BEGIN` and `\END` are only valid inside the `summary`-environment.

You can manually alter the indentation by giving the level as an optional argument to `summary` with the following meanings:

-1: part

0: chapter

1: section

2: subsection

3: subsubsection

Default is `0` resulting in chapter level of indentation.

Results if both `\ifSummaryInToC` and `\ifSummaryInText` are true:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot for your answer. This works great!

Comment: @orange Just don't nest other environments into it! That could go horribly wrong.

Comment: @orange I've made an edit allowing nested environments in a hacky way. Is it a problem for you, that the indentation on section level is equal to the one on chapter level (in ToC)?

Comment: I was going to ask whether the indentation can be adapted based on the heading level, but I thought this may be too difficult to achieve, so I didn't ;-). It's already good enough as it is, but if it isn't too much for you to add, then I would appreciate it.

Comment: @orange See my edit. But it requires the `enumitem` package (because I was too lazy to set the indentation manually) and requires some manual work (giving the current section's level as optional argument, default is `0` meaning chapter).